# Typecasting bytes properly for writing to a serial handle in C++

Tags: c++, casting, serial-port, char, ros

**Background**

I'm doing an Arduino port of code into C++ and having issues with the data being sent as unsigned char.  I need to send an 8 byte packet of unsigned chars consisting of:

```
Byte 1 - Header - 0xFF
Byte 2 - Right Joy Vertical - value between -100 to 100 shifted up by 128
Byte 3 - Right Joy Horizontal - value between -100 to 100 shifted up by 128
Byte 4 - Left Joy Vertical - value between -100 to 100 shifted up by 128
Byte 5 - Right Joy Horizontal - value between -100 to 100 shifted up by 128
Byte 6 - Button Values - 8 bit byte where each bit is mapped to a button
Byte 7 - Extended Inst. - "0" not needed
Byte 8 - Checksum
```

The arduino code had code written as:

```
Serial.write((unsigned char)right_V);
Serial.write((unsigned char)buttons);
```

This obviously isn't as easy in C++.

**Problems:**

1) How do I typecast properly to send 8 bytes of unsigned char by my 'sp->write()' function?

2) What printf modifiers do I use to display the data as unsigned char bytes in HEX?

**Code clarification**

`btn` is a struct consisting of double precision joystick values

`cmd[]` is an unsigned char array of size 8

`sp->write(const char * data, int length)` is a wrapper for the fstream write function. I've included the definition just in case.

`ROS_INFO` is a wrapper for printf for outputting to a ROS Console

**CODE**

```
// *****************************************************************************
// Create the Commander unsigned char packet as per the Arbotix Commander specifications 
int PhantomXROS::arbotixCmdPackage(cont_value btn)
{

int d_cmd=0;
unsigned char st_code;

std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << "0xFF";
ss >> st_code;

//Mapping joystick values to the servo values of the robot arm
int right_V=this->map(btn.rightV, -1, 1, -100, 100)+128;
int right_H=this->map(btn.rightH, -1, 1, -100, 100)+128;
int left_V=this->map(btn.leftV, -1, 1, -100, 100)+128;
int left_H=this->map(btn.leftH, -1, 1, -100, 100)+128;



//Bytes 1-5 Convert integers to bytes
this->cmd[0] = (unsigned char)st_code;
this->cmd[1] = (unsigned char)right_V;
this->cmd[2] = (unsigned char)right_H;
this->cmd[3] = (unsigned char)left_V;
this->cmd[4] = (unsigned char)left_H;

//Byte 6 - Assign a button ON/OFF to its corresponding bit
d_cmd += (btn.R1 > 0) ? 1 : 0;
d_cmd += (btn.R2 > 0) ? 2 : 0;
d_cmd += (btn.R3 > 0) ? 4 : 0;
d_cmd += (btn.L4 > 0) ? 8 : 0;
d_cmd += (btn.L5 > 0) ? 16 : 0;
d_cmd += (btn.L6 > 0) ? 32 : 0;
d_cmd += (btn.RT > 0) ? 64 : 0;
d_cmd += (btn.LT > 0) ? 128 : 0;
this->cmd[5] = (unsigned char)d_cmd;

//Byte 7 - Extended instruction - none, therefore 0
this->cmd[6] = (unsigned char)0;

//Byte 8 - Checksum
this->cmd[7] = (unsigned char)((255 - (right_V+right_H+left_V+left_H+d_cmd)%256));

//Reinterpret the cmd byte array to an 8 char string
std::string buf(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(cmd), 8);

//write to the arbotix serial handle
try{
    sp_->write(buf.c_str(),buf.size()); 

}
catch(cereal::Exception& e){ 
    ROS_INFO("Could not write to Arbotix:");
    ROS_BREAK();
    return(-1);
}


//Output data to the ROS console
if(this->timer > 500)
{


    ROS_INFO("Arbotix Cmd right_v has written: %d", right_V);
    ROS_INFO("Arbotix Cmd right_h has written: %d", right_H);
    ROS_INFO("Arbotix Cmd left_v has written: %d", left_V);
    ROS_INFO("Arbotix Cmd left_h has written: %d", left_H);
    ROS_INFO("Arbotix Cmd d_cmd has written: %d", d_cmd);
    ROS_INFO("String command: %s",buf.c_str());

    this->timer = 0;

}


return 0;


}
```

Below is the write code

```
int cereal::CerealPort::write(const char * data, int length)
00146 {
00147         int len = length==-1 ? strlen(data) : length;
00148 
00149         // IO is currently non-blocking. This is what we want for the more cerealon read case.
00150         int origflags = fcntl(fd_, F_GETFL, 0);
00151         fcntl(fd_, F_SETFL, origflags & ~O_NONBLOCK); // TODO: @todo can we make this all work in non-blocking?
00152         int retval = ::write(fd_, data, len);
00153         fcntl(fd_, F_SETFL, origflags | O_NONBLOCK);
00154 
00155         if(retval == len) return retval;
00156         else CEREAL_EXCEPT(cereal::Exception, "write failed");
00157 }
```

Comment: 1) i believe it's "SERIAL", not "CEREAL", but 2) I'm sure I'm not understanding your situation, but do you have control over ::write? why not const unsigned char * data?

Comment: also google printf, and you will see the either `x` or `X` modifier for hexadecimal display of numbers

Comment: You should really try to narrow it down to as few lines of code as possible, I'm fairly sure that in doing so you will probably find that it's as easy in C++ as it was in C. The process of deconstructing the problem is usually a great way to actually solve it.

Comment: Also, instead of fcntl wrapped around ::write just use `::send(fd_, data, len, origflags & ~O_NONBLOCK);` see http://linux.die.net/man/2/send

Comment: @AK4749 I'm using the ROS system, and a cereal is the name of the serial comm. package within it.  I don't have control over it, but I did copy its code over and tried set the data input parameter as  const unsigned char* - it gave errors.

Comment: @kfsone, Thank you for the link.  I'm not sure what you mean by reducing the lines of code, but for the code I'm writing its in a rough dev stage.

Comment: I mean narrow the sample code down to the minimal number of lines to demonstrate the issue you are having. You posted ~100 lines of code in regards to a casting problem; the best way to get help here, and potentially to avoid needing to ask for it, is to boil the issue down to the minimal number of lines to replicate/demonstrate it in a runable way - something you can paste into ideone.com that will run.  If it doesn't help you solve it yourself, it shows research effort on your part and makes it easier for overflowers to focus on the actual problem you have and not the rest of your code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your typecasting is correct but using `std:string` is not necessary here. You can use the `cmd` buffer directly in your call to `sp_->write()`

```
//write to the arbotix serial handle
try
{
    sp_->write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(cmd), 8);
}
catch(cereal::Exception& e){ 
    ROS_INFO("Could not write to Arbotix:");
    ROS_BREAK();
    return(-1);
}
```

To print the data in hex format you can use the `%02x` or `%02X` format specifiers like so

```
ROS_INFO("Arbotix Cmd right_v has written: %02X", right_V);
```

This tells the `printf` function (used by `ROS_INFO`) to print at least two hexadecimal digits and prepend a zero character if less than two digits are output.

Comment: I think this works as its outputting the correct bytes to the console.  Thank you!